# CoreData related crash in ViewDidLoad

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to add an item using CoreData like this:

```
func createfirstItem() {
     let item = Item(context: dataController.viewContext)
     item.name = "Name"

     itemList.append(item)
     itemsCV.reloadData()
}
```

It works when ran in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillAppear`, but crashed with the error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` when ran in `viewDidLoad`. I *could* run it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewWillAppear` but this causes the functions to be ran several times as the view controller presents `Page Sheet` style.

Looking at other questions here the issue may be CoreData not having loaded yet in `viewDidLoad`. What can I do?

Comment: can you show your `viewDidLoad()` function ?

Comment: i need to know what is nil in your case ...

Comment: `viewDidLoad()` just has that `createFirstItem()` function @jawadAli

Comment: what is `itemsCV`

Comment: The collection view

Comment: how you build collectionView ? is it in storyboard ?

Comment: Yes, storyboard.

Comment: can you share crash logs ?

Comment: itemList is optional ?